# В контактной форме не переведён пункт "I want to report a Community Emergency"

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, инструменты-модератора, контактная-форма

https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/contact

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Какая-то модераторская хрень. Нет такого у обычных пользователей.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ D: помечали бы хоть как-то

Comment: Помечено английскими буквами :)

Comment: @Qwertiy надо бы проверить и пометить красным, если готово.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, ага: https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6NxW.png.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавил/обновил/проверил некоторые переводы:

- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/11402
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/11401
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/11404
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/11406
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/11403
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/11405
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/11398
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/11399
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/11400

Будет на сайте в новых сборках. Текущая rev 2021.6.11.39480